# java exec() run a db2 import command, waitfor() never return

Tags: java, process, import, db2, runtime.exec

I used java process run a external command.
This command is .bat file with some db2 commands.
When I want use the process waiffor() return a result, I can't get anything. The program must be block.

java code:

```
.....

Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p = null;     

String command = "db2cmd -c -w -i C:/import1.bat";

p = rt.exec(command);   
p.waitFor();

.....
```

import1.bat:

```
@echo off
db2 connect to text_DB user text using tesxt0114  

db2 IMPORT FROM "C:\MVCMSInputFiles\IIS20121224180129.csv" OF DEL METHOD P (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16) MESSAGES "C:\MVCMSInputFiles\20121224180129.log" INSERT INTO BLUEX.BIZ_MACHINE (MACHINE_SSERIALNO, MACHINE_STYPE, MACHINE_SPROJECTID, MACHINE_SCATEGORY, MACHINE_SNAME, MACHINE_SBRAND, MACHINE_SSPOT, MACHINE_SPRODUCEDATE, MACHINE_SSERVPERIOD, MACHINE_SENDDATE, MACHINE_SCONTRACTID, MACHINE_SSERVSTATUS, MACHINE_NSTATUS, MACHINE_SSCID, LOG_SLASTUSER, MACHINE_TSIMPORTTIME) 

db2 connect reset
```

---

I also use  `p.getInputStream()` to handle `InputStream`, but the process always be block by the 3rd command `(db2 import.....)`

javacode:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p = null;

String command = "db2cmd -c -w -i C:/import1.bat";

p = rt.exec(command);

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null){              
   System.out.println(line);            
}

reader.close();

while(true){                
    if (p.waitFor() == 0) break;            
}
```

---

When I used `db2 export...` or `db2 select * from ....` replace the 3rd command. The function `waitfor` can return a result. The process can't be block.

That's too weird.

Comment: 1) Read the Java World article linked from the [`exec` tag Wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/runtime.exec/info) & implement the recommendations.  If it does not solve the problem, it will at least provide more information on the failure.  2) Use a `ProcessBuilder` rather than `Runtime.exec()` 3) Break the `String command` into `String[] commands`. 4) Why the blank 'every other line' in the code of that post?  Does it make it run faster? 5) ..What *is* your question?

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer about this question.
reason is :
Before the p = rt.exec(command), there is connection object that not commit.
so the code like this can run correctly.

```
.... ...
ConnectionFactory.commit(conn);
p = rt.exec(command); 
... ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Mabye you can do like :

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p = null;     

String command = "db2cmd -c -w -i C:/import1.bat";

p = rt.exec(command); 
p.getInputStream().close();  
p.waitFor();
```

holp can help you.