# How to execute cmd command in Java class?

Tags: java, process, cmd, runtime.exec

I want to call cmd command in java code. I say:

```
String str ="C:/uploaded_files/111.txt";
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"cmd.exe", "/c",str});
System.out.println(str);
```

And dont get `111.txt`. Its strange because when this code was in `jsp` all works fine. What can be wrong?

Comment: What outcome would you expect from running the program, and what do you actually get?

Comment: it might be related with file writing permissions.

Comment: Follow the same advice I gave in comment to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14029122/418556).

Comment: @Gustav Grusell Hmm i want to get 111.txt in `C:/uploaded_files` folder. But folder still empty.

Comment: Well he most likely got just the String printed. He never asked for the process output.

Comment: If you are not getting the files in C:/uploaded_files then thats a problem in different part of our code.

Comment: @ Jayamohan its whole my code. Nothing else.

Comment: @KliverMax are you having the file 111.txt in C:/uploaded_files?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Open an existing file? Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"notepad", str}) or create a new file? Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"cmd", "/c","echo", "some text", ">", str}) but a better solution would be new File(str).createNewFile();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what's the problem with this code. It's perfectly working. opens and shows content of the file 111.txt

```
try {
    String str ="C:/uploaded_files/111.txt";
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"cmd.exe", "/c",str});
    System.out.println(str);
    } catch (Exception ex) {}
```

please check whether the path is correct and whether the directories and files are not missed or spelled

Answer (score 0):

I hope It is not **cmd.exe** Please try this:

```
String[] command = new String[3];
command[0] = "cmd";
command[1] = "/c";
command[2] = "C:/uploaded_files/111.txt";

Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec (command);
```

Comment: What you mean `I hope It is not cmd.exe`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open the file in notepad try this.

```
String file = "C:/uploaded_files/111.txt";

Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd", "/c", "notepad.exe", file);
```

Hope it's the one you want.